# Using TTS to tell user when the stopwatch reaches a certain time

Tags: c#

I have written a simple stopwatch application for work and my boss would like it to tell you when you reaches a certain time i.e. at 15 min say "15 minutes has elapsed.", at 30 min say "30 minutes has elapsed.", etc.  I have looked all over the web for implementation of TTS however I am drawing a blank on how to implement it into my existing application.  I believe I have a good understanding of how it all works but as mentioned before I am drawing a blank on how to integrate it into my app.  The application is a windows form application.  Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CiscoSw
{
    public partial class SwForm : Form
    {


        private readonly Stopwatch _sw = new Stopwatch();

        public SwForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            startBtn.Text = @"Start";
            UpdateDisplay();
        }

        private void SwForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentTimeUtc.Start();
        }

        private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_sw.IsRunning)
            {
                _sw.Start();
                stopwatchTimer.Start();
                startBtn.Text = @"Stop";
                UpdateDisplay();
            }
            else
            {
                _sw.Stop();
                stopwatchTimer.Stop();
                startBtn.Text = @"Start";
            }
        }

        private void resetBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_sw.IsRunning)
            {
                _sw.Restart();
            }
            else
            {
                _sw.Reset();
            }
            UpdateDisplay();
        }

        private void stopwatchTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateDisplay();
        }

        private void UpdateDisplay()
        {
            stopwatchTimeLabel.Text =
                $"{_sw.Elapsed.Hours.ToString("00")}:{_sw.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString("00")}:{_sw.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString("00")}";
        }

        private void currentTimeUtc_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            DateTime timenow = DateTime.UtcNow;
            displayCurrentTime.Text = $"{timenow:M/d/yyyy   HHmm Zulu}";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to display the value of the stopwatch in label ??

Comment: Note: Since you're using string interpolation, how about using it sensibly? `$"{_sw.Elapsed.Hours:00}...`

Comment: Kyle the stopwatch does display in the label, what needs to happen is that when the timer for the stopwatch label reaches say 15 min the user is notified via TTS.

Comment: Sami,  I thought I did use string interpolation correctly.  Please enlighten as to what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the following assembly in your project:

```
System.Speech.dll
```

In your update display you will have to check the intervals (15m, 30m) and perform TTS. To do that you would need to implement the following:

```
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(); // create this only once for reuse

synthesizer.Speak("the time interval that has lapsed");
```

If you dont have the Microsoft Speech installed on your computer, you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=27224).

You can configure the Speech Recognition and TTS (voice etc.) by going to:

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Speech Recognition
```

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive response.  I have been racking my brain for weeks now trying to figure this out.  Once again thank you.

Comment: @JonP, you are welcome. Please mark the answer correct otherwise members will still view your question thinking it is unanswered.